# How can I view my profile?

Tags: ios, fantasica

In fantasica, whenever you try to recruit an ally or battle another player, you can see their personal, player stats.  The problem that I am having is that I cannot find a way to view my own profile!  Does any one know if this can be done and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you just scroll the menu at the bottom! All the way to the right, you'll see Profile

[image: Profile menu item]

Comment: Thanks, but this is an old questions and I don't play any more.  I do know that the interface to the game changed no less than 3 times, while I was playing it.  There is a chance that Mobage has updated the game (again) and added this information.  Take a screenshot and I'll give you the answer.